# "Error: 'target' is a required option" when running imported function from `<script context="module">`

Tags: svelte

I have a Error.svelte component which has a `<script context="module">` containing a writable store and a exported 'addError' function, altering the store content.

###### Error.svelte

```js
<script context="module">

    import {get, writable} from "svelte/store";

    let errorStore = writable([])

    export function addError(error) {
        let errors = get(errorStore)
        errors.push(error)
        errorStore.set(errors)
        throw error
    }
</script>
```

###### App.svelte

```html
<script>
    import Error, {addError} from './Error.svelte'
    import DifferentComp from './DifferentComp.svelte'  
</script>

<Error />

<button on:click={() => addError(new Error('error message'))}>
    addError() from App
</button>

<DifferentComp />
```

###### DifferentComp .svelte

```html
<script>
import {addError} from './Error.svelte'

</script>

<button on:click={() => addError(new Error('error message'))}>
    addError() from DifferentComp
</button>
```

When importing and running this function from the component works fine, but from App.svelte I get the error message "Error: 'target' is a required option"

See [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/64fed2b7d1b6486885851650aa89c83c?version=3.44.0) for a live demo

Is there a difference when importing from App.svelte to importing from another component and there's a reason for the error, or is this simply a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your `App.svelte`, you are shadowing the global `Error` constructor with the imported `Error` svelte component. Inside `DifferentComp` `new Error()` means "create an error", whereas in `App.svelte` it means "create an instance of the Error component". Rename the default import to something else and it works.